# PLS-DA algorithm in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Partial Least Squares (PLS) algorithm is implemented in the scikit-learn library, as documented here:
http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/auto_examples/plot_pls.html
In the case where y is a binary vector, a variant of this algorithm is being used, the Partial least squares Discriminant Analysis (PLS-DA) algorithm. 
Does the PLSRegression module in sklearn.pls implements also this binary case? If not, where can I find a python implementation for it?
In my binary case, I'm trying to use the PLSRegression:

```
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=10)
pls.fit(x, y)
x_r, y_r = pls.transform(x, y, copy=True)
```

In the transform function, the code gets exception in this line:

```
y_scores = np.dot(Yc, self.y_rotations_)
```

The error message is "ValueError: matrices are not aligned". Yc is the normalized y vector, and self.y_rotations_ = [1.]. 
In the fit function, self.y_rotations_ = np.ones(1) if the original y is a univariate vector (y.shape[1](http://scikit-learn.org/0.12/auto_examples/plot_pls.html)=1).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have tried the same method (using the latest version of scikit-learn) and it seems to do PLS-DA perfectly. The key is to label classes with 1 and 0 (for same/other class). If you still can't get it to work, can you post your data?

Comment: Haven't resolved it yet, but I'll try user3178149 solution. Thanks for offering your help!

Comment: @mfitzp Is partial least squares regression the same as partial least squares discriminant analysis? I am trying to figure out how to get plots from the first two components.

Comment: @O.rka correct, PLSDA for two groups is just PLS Regression against a binary variable (0 or 1) representing group membership. See [here](http://mfitzp.io/article/partial-least-squares-discriminant-analysis-plsda/) for a longer write up.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've just recently gotten introduced to ordination and I want to understand it before I start implementing it.  Wow. AMAZING tutorial

Answer (score 34, accepted):

PLS-DA is really a "trick" to use PLS for categorical outcomes instead of the usual continuous vector/matrix.  The trick consists of creating a dummy identity matrix of zeros/ones which represents membership to each of the categories. So if you have a binary outcome to be predicted (i.e. male/female , yes/no, etc) your dummy matrix will have TWO columns representing the membership to either category.

For example, consider the outcome gender for four people: 2 males and 2 females. The dummy matrix should be coded as :

```
import numpy as np
dummy=np.array([[1,1,0,0],[0,0,1,1]]).T
```

, where each column represents the membership to the two categories (male, female)

Then your model for data in variable Xdata ( shape 4 rows,arbitrary columns ) would be:

```
myplsda=PLSRegression().fit(X=Xdata,Y=dummy)
```

The predicted categories can be extracted from comparison of the two indicator variables in mypred:

```
mypred= myplsda.predict(Xdata)
```

For each row/case the predicted gender is that with the highest predicted membership.

Comment: If your data contains only two classes, it is better to present y as a single column then do regression, and identify the class using threshold of half value of the two class value, for example, if 1 is for class one and -1 for the other class, threshold is 0. There exist problems if a matrix of y is used. This is also why PLSDA is not recommended for multiclass problem. See paper _Partial least squares discriminant analysis: taking the magic away_ for detail discussion.

Comment: @Elkan: if you meant [this](file:///C:/Users/adm/Downloads/Brereton_et_al-2014-Journal_of_Chemometrics-1.pdf) paper - the whole sense there - "An alternative to PLS1 is to use PLS2 [5,6]. It is not the purpose
of this paper to expand on the PLS2 algorithm" -- do not forget that everything is being done with computer calculations (very quick!) & for arguments in the paper there really exists tips from linear vector algebra -- the author himself didn't prove his abusive viewpoint in the paper with certain algorithmic details he tried (whenever)

Comment: @JeeyCi You should go through that section very detail where the author already discussed the problems using one-vs-all strategy or making the `Y` as a matrix for PLS-DA to classify multi-class data. BTW, your link is not working.

Comment: [dawnloadable link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mike-Lane/post/What_is_the_difference_between_principal_components_analysis_and_partial_least_squares_discriminant_analysis/attachment/5ab3e9dc4cde266d58932c8e/AS%3A607036769329152%401521740252269/download/Brereton_et_al-2014-Journal_of_Chemometrics-1.pdf) - I just don't understand why the author hesitate to use Geographically Weighting (using vectors), though of course the problem of Multicollinearity can cause biased estimations in any Analysis

Comment: and besides, from article: "LDA with prior reduction of dimensionality can perform just as well." -- dimensionality reduction with PCA (without consideration to target dependency with features) seems Not good alternative at all. After such dim-reduction can be left only features not affecting the target. (to my viewpoint)

Comment: In general, [17 variable selection methods in PLS](https://analyticalsciencejournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cem.3226). And chapter here[6.7.7. How the PLS model is calculated](https://learnche.org/pid/latent-variable-modelling/projection-to-latent-structures/how-the-pls-model-is-calculated) with additional 6.7.4. A geometric interpretation of PLS

Comment: @Elkan: just 1 remark to avoid misunderstanding of my comment above: PLS solves the problem of multicollinearity as so as PC1 is the linear combination with the largest possible explained variation && PC2 is the best of what is left -- following assumptions of Linearity for this analysis. I just meant that if either from more than 2 features have some correlations than vector algebra helps (as geograhical distances between point) -- & this is task for PLS2 (as I understood from other sources), but in the article PLS2 algo is ommited. Anyway, thanks for the link

Comment: [PCA+LDA vs PLS-DA](https://www.hrpub.org/download/20190930/MS4-13490705.pdf) research && [PLS-DA+LDA](https://www.researchgate.net/post/PLS-DA-or-LDA-for-NIR-analysis) discussion

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Linear Discriminate Analysis package in SKLearn, it will take integers for the y value:

[LDA-SKLearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html)

Here is a short tutorial on how to use the LDA:
[sklearn LDA tutorial](https://www.idtools.com.au/classification-nir-spectra-linear-discriminant-analysis-python/)

Comment: ... when having >1 latent variable - [discussed here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455551/difference-between-lda-and-pls-da)

Answer (score 0):

I know this had been answered thoroughly but I wanted to add what worked for me just in case it's helpful for anyone else who finds this question:

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.mfitzp.com/partial-least-squares-discriminant-analysis-plsda/) which deals with this in the following way:

(I had a dataset where the variables were AD and CN)

```
#Create a pseudolinear Y value against which to correlate the samples 
#(in my case I used AD)
y = [g == 'AD' for g in df.columns.get_level_values(0)]
y

#Conversion of boolean values to numerical
y = np.array(y, dtype=int)
y

#continue as normal with your PLS-DA model
plsr = PLSRegression(n_components=2, scale=False)
plsr.fit(df.values.T, y)
```